# Modify the value of a model field during serialization

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I have a system that is deployed on 7 servers, one of them we consider as the main server. For statistical reasons now I must synchronize the data. This presents a peculiarity, since one of the data of the model in the server has a value but in the other servers it is different.

Example: `clinic = 10` on the main server, but on the second server `clinic = 34`

I made an endpoint that will load the data from the other servers to the main server, for which I am getting the value of the clinic from an environment variable.

I require that when serializing the data from the other servers, the clinic value is that of the environment variable and not that of the database.

## Main server

models.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    clinic = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Clinic', null=True, blank=True)
    profesional = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Profesional')
    user = models.ForeignKey(Users, verbose_name='User RCF', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='creation date')
```

serializers.py

```
class BaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    creation_date = serializers.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        extra_kwargs = {
            'id': {'required': False}
        }

class MyModelSerializer(AuditoriaBaseSerializer):

    class Meta(BaseSerializer.Meta):
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class CreateManyMixin(CreateModelMixin):

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

class MyModelViewSet(CreateManyMixin, GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
```

I use the serializers both for the creation of the payload that the servers will send, and for the views for which the main server will serve

## Other servers

services.py

```
model = MyModel
serializer = MyModelSerializer
data = model.objects.filter(fecha_creacion__date=date)
serialized_data = serializer(data, many=True).data
requests.post(url, json=serialized_data)
```

I tried passing the value of the environment variable through the serializer context but this didn't fix my problem

`serialized_data = serializer(data, many=True context={'clinic': int(config('ID_CLINIC'))}).data`

I need to get

```
[
    {
        "id": 420,
        "creation_date": "2023-04-13T11:31:59.535634-05:00",
        "user": 1,
        "clinica": 10,
        "profesional": "Juan"
    },
    {
        "id": 421,
        "creation_date": "2023-03-18T09:58:23.537605-05:00",
        "usuario": 2,
        "clinica": 10,
        "profesional": "Ana"
    },
]
```

instead of

```
[
    {
        "id": 420,
        "creation_date": "2023-04-13T11:31:59.535634-05:00",
        "user": 1,
        "clinica": 34,
        "profesional": "Juan"
    },
    {
        "id": 421,
        "creation_date": "2023-03-18T09:58:23.537605-05:00",
        "usuario": 2,
        "clinica": 34,
        "profesional": "Ana"
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i think one approach to solve this issue could be to override the to_representation method of your serializer to replace the value of the "clinic" field with the value from the environment variable. Here is an example implementation:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta(BaseSerializer.Meta):
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super().to_representation(instance)
        representation['clinic'] = int(config('ID_CLINIC'))
        return representation
```

This implementation overrides the to_representation method of the serializer to replace the "clinic" value in the serialized data with the value from the environment variable. When you call serializer(data, many=True).data, the serializer will use this custom to_representation method to generate the serialized data.

You can use this serializer on the main server and the other servers to ensure that the "clinic" value is consistent across all servers.

I hope i understood what you needed.